# javascript - how to automatically check checkbox when adding value to textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, textbox

I know a little about javascript in ASP.NET. I put textbox next to checkbox control. So when you type in a textbox, checkbox should automatically get checked. And when you erase string in textbox, the checkbox should automatically get unchecked. How to code in javascript?

What I am trying to code here is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function TextboxFunction() {
        if (document.getElementById("txtQuestion").textContent != null)
            document.getElementById("cbxYes").checked = true;

        if (document.getElementById("txtQuestion").textContent == null)
            document.getElementById("cbxYes").checked = false;
    }
</script>
```

Asp.net (listview)

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="item" runat="server">
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" OnChange="javascript:TextboxFunction();" AutoPostBack="true" Width="200px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox ID="cbxYes" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="True" /></td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the property you are using. Try .value instead of .textContent.

But, also: I see that you are using grids, then. I asume it is probably that you have more than one checkbox with the id: "cbxYes".

I would recommend you to go to http://api.jQuery.com  and check the methods $(this).before() and .closest() to find the checkbox that you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

It might work to change from `.textContent` to `.Value`, and change `Null` to `""`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function TextboxFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("txtQuestion").Value != "")
        document.getElementById("cbxYes").checked = true;
    if (document.getElementById("txtQuestion").Value == "")
        document.getElementById("cbxYes").checked = false;
}
```

Comment: Also, you can skip the last `if` check . . . just change `if (document.getElementById("txtQuestion").Value == "")` to `else`.

Comment: I'll just take a wild guess and say that this would cause an error, something like "HTMLelement has no property Value", as it's case sensitive.

Comment: You're welcome Brett. Loved the THOR video btw, cracked me up! They deleted some of my comments in the other question, about the Apple IIe thing I spoke about lol don't know if you did see it or not. @BrettFromLA

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did see that! I'm an "old guy" too -- especially since Apple ][+ was before Apple ][e! Heck, my computer didn't even have lower case letters. You Apple ][e users had it good. XD

Comment: LOL, well Brett, what my message did say to much that I can remember was, that we used an Apple IIe back in the mid-80's but wasn't used for programming but for the graphic arts industry. Which I then wrote "Yeah, I'm that old, lol" so we're about in the same age group. Also said that the 9inch boot disk cost $90 back then. One didn't want to mess one up, which the boss back then happened to stick his fingers on the exposed area (once). Oh well, he was loaded, so no biggie; he could afford it ;-) @BrettFromLA - We had what was considered (cutting edge) "state-of-the-art" technology lol!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `onChange` event only fires after an input loses focus. Try capturing the `onKeyPress` event on `txtQuestion`. In the event handler, check `document.getElementById("txtQuestion").value.length >= 0` and check or uncheck the checkbox as appropriate.

Edit: The `onKeyUp` event will work better than `onKeyPress` in this case.

Comment: not working for me. can u please give ur full code so that i can understand. thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
document.getElementById("txtQuestion").value
```

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("txtQuestion").textContent
```

Comment: It's value actually. It's case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

As you are using ItemTemplate I asume that is in a repeater or something like that. In that case, the ID you put in the control won't be the same as the one it's rendered in the HTML, as you will end up having several controls with the same Id. Asp.Net handles that.

What you can do is something like this:

```
 <ItemTemplate>
     <tr class="item" runat="server">
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" OnChange="TextboxFunction(this);" Width="200px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td><asp:CheckBox ID="cbxYes" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

And JS:

```
function TextboxFunction(textbox) {
    var textBoxTd = textbox.parentNode;
    var checkboxTd = textBoxTD.nextSibling;
    var chx = checkboxTd.childNodes[0];
    chx.checked = textbox.value == "";
}
```

You are passing the textbox as a parameter so you don't have to get it by the id. Then you look for the checkbox that is in the next TD and apply the logic. For this kind of things, JQuery is much more easy to work with than pure javascript